# Remove images during Duplication of a product Programmatically

Tags: event-observer, product-images

When Clicking the duplicate button, how do we NOT copy over the images when we duplicate a Magento product?

Attributes are easy.

> $new_product = $observer->getNewProduct( );
>
> $new_product->setErpBinLocation(null)

Answer (score 0):

simply check the last option "remove" for the images you want to remove in image section.

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question to help assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
$new_product->unsetData('image')
    ->unsetData('small_image')
    ->unsetData('thumbnail')
    ->unsetData('media_gallery');
```